# Facebook login in a small modal view

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, authentication, modalviewcontroller

In the application I' currently developing, i need the user to log on Facebook. For the time being, a webview filling the whole screen allows that but I would like the login view to be displayed only on a modal view taking just a smaller part of the screen. Does anyone know if this is possible and in that case how to do that ?

Great thanks

Benja

Comment: Did you find out this Ben?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a webview then I would suggest using our pre-built login feature found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/).